# Using Beautiful soup to create a looping svg animation from multiple svg frames

Tags: python, animation, svg, beautifulsoup

I have 3 svgs. Each is the same picture with a few curves adjusted, [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/5no9wqkd/2/).

I'm trying to find all the `path` tags that share the same `id` between each of the 3 svgs, but which contain different values for the `d` attribute.

I would like this program to create a looping svg animation from the svgs that I give as input to it. For example, given the 3 svgs linked above, I would like to receive this svg as a result

```html
<svg height="30%" width="30%" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1425 1235" width="100%" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g>
<path d="M90.388,477.489c7.93,5.522 42.72,23.778 123.168,25.247l45.723,-146.361c35.197,-88.293 103.007,-173.582 188.525,-226.095c195.6,-120.109 443.676,-217.47 662.8,28.084c104.856,117.503 230.626,438.387 191.262,597.334c-7.603,30.699 -25.306,55.182 -28.377,78.869c32.654,102.706 75.639,172.731 131.01,239.734c42.352,51.247 -23.008,47.671 -73.889,22.326c-42.381,-21.111 -117.313,-82.062 -151.526,-129.06c-23.69,21.907 -48.312,43.978 -72.72,75.938c-5.334,6.985 -13.545,14.662 -24.216,22.653c-60.06,-5.641 -138.855,-2.492 -223.856,10.82c-119.253,18.677 -220.758,52.665 -272.729,87.741c-4.774,-1.651 -9.453,-3.461 -14.054,-5.403c-100.972,-42.615 -148.831,-90.767 -202.921,-151.15c-4.588,81.511 -47.64,156.094 -73.572,182.59c-48.323,49.376 -110.427,65.954 -65.61,-50.043c32.486,-84.083 42.849,-170.372 27.032,-257.969c4.406,9.107 7.802,14.023 15.683,21.643c-4.451,-4.367 -9.035,-8.794 -13.756,-13.276c-33.672,-31.964 -55.079,-100.363 -59.596,-171.002c-63.473,37.984 -111.095,23.103 -168.621,-0.648c-80.364,-123.877 66.105,-87.749 60.24,-241.972c-2.541,-1.752 -2.338,-2.214 -0.01,-0.416l0.01,0.416Z" id="body" style="fill:#e1e1c5;stroke:#000;stroke-width:12px;"><animate attributeName="d" begin="0s;body3.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="body1" to="M90.388,477.489c7.93,5.522 42.72,23.778 123.168,25.247l45.723,-146.361c35.197,-88.293 103.007,-173.582 188.525,-226.095c195.6,-120.109 443.676,-217.47 662.8,28.084c104.856,117.503 230.626,438.387 191.262,597.334c-7.603,30.699 -16.034,56.471 -25.146,78.55c28.108,106.676 75.609,192.707 28.097,269.683c-34.29,52.099 -53.98,44.382 -64.302,-1.716c-4.855,-35.336 -40.168,-71.575 -61.431,-134.648c-23.69,21.907 -48.312,43.978 -72.72,75.938c-5.334,6.985 -13.545,14.662 -24.216,22.653c-60.06,-5.641 -138.855,-2.492 -223.856,10.82c-119.253,18.677 -220.758,52.665 -272.729,87.741c-4.774,-1.651 -9.453,-3.461 -14.054,-5.403c-100.972,-42.615 -148.831,-90.767 -202.921,-151.15c1.683,67.906 24.023,110.639 41.511,140.039c31.774,53.42 24.85,94.64 -62.422,23.645c-84.554,-89.521 -119.559,-192.668 -99.02,-288.78c7.752,6.502 15.583,13.697 23.464,21.317c-4.451,-4.367 -9.035,-8.794 -13.756,-13.276c-33.672,-31.964 -55.079,-100.363 -59.596,-171.002c-63.473,37.984 -111.095,23.103 -168.621,-0.648c-80.364,-123.877 66.105,-87.749 60.24,-241.972c-2.541,-1.752 -2.338,-2.214 -0.01,-0.416l0.01,0.416Z"/><animate attributeName="d" begin="body1.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="body2" to="M90.388,477.489c7.93,5.522 42.72,23.778 123.168,25.247l45.723,-146.361c35.197,-88.293 103.007,-173.582 188.525,-226.095c195.6,-120.109 443.676,-217.47 662.8,28.084c104.856,117.503 230.626,438.387 191.262,597.334c-7.603,30.699 -25.306,55.182 -28.377,78.869c54.824,95.73 123.021,166.489 97.108,253.157c-19.597,59.211 -40.615,56.868 -62.545,15.027c-13.857,-32.867 -77.195,-101.72 -128.968,-135.184c-23.69,21.907 -48.312,43.978 -72.72,75.938c-5.334,6.985 -13.545,14.662 -24.216,22.653c-60.06,-5.641 -138.855,-2.492 -223.856,10.82c-119.253,18.677 -220.758,52.665 -272.729,87.741c-4.774,-1.651 -9.453,-3.461 -14.054,-5.403c-100.972,-42.615 -148.831,-90.767 -202.921,-151.15c-45.305,34.069 -77.472,148.605 -73.572,182.59c7.086,61.75 -16.126,96.51 -66.629,-4.019c-40.43,-116.313 -30.079,-224.746 28.051,-303.993c4.406,9.107 7.802,14.023 15.683,21.643c-4.451,-4.367 -9.035,-8.794 -13.756,-13.276c-33.672,-31.964 -55.079,-100.363 -59.596,-171.002c-63.473,37.984 -111.095,23.103 -168.621,-0.648c-80.364,-123.877 66.105,-87.749 60.24,-241.972c-2.541,-1.752 -2.338,-2.214 -0.01,-0.416l0.01,0.416Z"/><animate attributeName="d" begin="body2.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="body3" to="M90.388,477.489c7.93,5.522 42.72,23.778 123.168,25.247l45.723,-146.361c35.197,-88.293 103.007,-173.582 188.525,-226.095c195.6,-120.109 443.676,-217.47 662.8,28.084c104.856,117.503 230.626,438.387 191.262,597.334c-7.603,30.699 -25.306,55.182 -28.377,78.869c32.654,102.706 75.639,172.731 131.01,239.734c42.352,51.247 -23.008,47.671 -73.889,22.326c-42.381,-21.111 -117.313,-82.062 -151.526,-129.06c-23.69,21.907 -48.312,43.978 -72.72,75.938c-5.334,6.985 -13.545,14.662 -24.216,22.653c-60.06,-5.641 -138.855,-2.492 -223.856,10.82c-119.253,18.677 -220.758,52.665 -272.729,87.741c-4.774,-1.651 -9.453,-3.461 -14.054,-5.403c-100.972,-42.615 -148.831,-90.767 -202.921,-151.15c-4.588,81.511 -47.64,156.094 -73.572,182.59c-48.323,49.376 -110.427,65.954 -65.61,-50.043c32.486,-84.083 42.849,-170.372 27.032,-257.969c4.406,9.107 7.802,14.023 15.683,21.643c-4.451,-4.367 -9.035,-8.794 -13.756,-13.276c-33.672,-31.964 -55.079,-100.363 -59.596,-171.002c-63.473,37.984 -111.095,23.103 -168.621,-0.648c-80.364,-123.877 66.105,-87.749 60.24,-241.972c-2.541,-1.752 -2.338,-2.214 -0.01,-0.416l0.01,0.416Z"/></path>
<path d="M585.563,1164.72c51.971,-35.076 153.476,-69.064 272.729,-87.741c85.001,-13.312 163.796,-16.461 223.856,-10.82c-86.627,65.685 -334.207,156.146 -496.585,98.561Z" style="fill:#eeeede;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M491.04,1016.28c25.012,82.237 -161.376,-72.451 -218.335,-247.372c-68.632,-210.764 57.284,-360.766 52.17,-274.215c-8.661,146.603 41.575,221.509 78.637,257.145c42.743,41.098 -9.601,103.399 87.528,264.442Z" style="fill:#c4c59b;"/>
<path d="M608.243,298.276c286.93,-208.386 579.038,53.527 581.314,239.179c1.311,106.901 -46.786,260.387 -181.162,379.856c-137.592,122.327 -372.812,92.552 -453.901,-2.045c-189.563,-221.139 -39.975,-548.922 53.749,-616.99Z" style="fill:#e0d4bc;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M608.243,298.276c286.93,-208.386 579.038,53.527 581.314,239.179c1.311,106.901 -46.786,260.387 -181.162,379.856c-137.592,122.327 -372.812,92.552 -453.901,-2.045c-189.563,-221.139 -39.975,-548.922 53.749,-616.99Z" style="fill:#e0d4bc;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M565.155,377.691c-23.615,-75.845 254.333,-256.51 424.936,-115.441c145.506,120.315 126.534,227.928 46.861,172.366c-57.471,-40.079 -48.051,54.217 -83.708,90.688c-35.657,36.471 -29.422,-9.567 -21.867,-19.041c7.554,-9.473 23.436,-96.936 1.747,-124.383c-58.176,-73.624 -198.545,-148.967 -367.969,-4.189" style="fill:#434132;"/>
<path d="M361.774,452.286c15.776,39.392 326.932,-421.84 620.369,-234.755c101.254,64.556 54.669,-74.266 44.171,-104.085c-78.269,-222.301 -821.486,-53.05 -664.54,338.84Z" style="fill:#9b9365;"/>
<path d="M662.652,556.91c0,0 81.041,73.154 119.613,41.832c72.749,-59.073 164.032,-3.563 145.686,-29.31c-58.111,-81.55 -170.816,-64.419 -186.627,-92.966c-46.561,-84.068 23.43,-97.087 104.307,-84.059c46.312,7.46 12.796,-60.085 -72.787,-51.897c-85.584,8.189 -59.975,-36.02 -213,113.129c-45.652,44.497 -43.024,107.692 -14.766,131.964c24.351,20.917 76.667,11.144 117.574,-28.693Z" style="fill:#bbae84;"/>
<circle cx="761.392" cy="595.569" r="569.218" style="fill:none;"/>
<ellipse cx="761.348" cy="588.604" rx="573.642" ry="587.275" style="fill:none;"/>
<path d="M732.491,416.621c0,-0 88.324,-88.758 120.589,57.231c2.426,10.974 -25.186,-8.243 -43.227,-6.769c-16.291,1.331 -99.375,10.412 -77.362,-50.462Z" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M732.491,416.621c0,-0 88.324,-88.758 120.589,57.231c2.426,10.974 -25.186,-8.243 -43.227,-6.769c-16.291,1.331 -99.375,10.412 -77.362,-50.462Z" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M815.097,462.006c-0,-0 14.765,-10.241 16.439,-19.155c0.565,-3.008 4.131,24.514 -16.439,19.155Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M815.097,462.006c-0,-0 14.765,-10.241 16.439,-19.155c0.565,-3.008 4.131,24.514 -16.439,19.155Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M1019.77,559.134c8.027,-34.362 95.3,-29.021 72.988,41.685c-18.787,59.537 -77.6,-21.939 -72.988,-41.685Z" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M1019.77,559.134c8.027,-34.362 95.3,-29.021 72.988,41.685c-18.787,59.537 -77.6,-21.939 -72.988,-41.685Z" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<use height="28px" transform="matrix(-0.951159,0.308701,-0.308701,-0.951159,3393.28,2047.46)" width="15px" x="1782" xlink:href="#_Image1" y="2126"/>
<use height="28px" transform="matrix(-0.951159,0.308701,-0.308701,-0.951159,3393.28,2047.46)" width="15px" x="1782" xlink:href="#_Image1" y="2126"/>
<path d="M658.11,415.392c0,-0 69.359,-48.596 37.383,-54.906c-8.234,-1.625 -37.383,54.906 -37.383,54.906Z" style="fill:#090000;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<path d="M887.503,728.479c0,0 15.894,-29.445 14.615,-42.536c-1.279,-13.091 -67.177,-73.041 -39.424,-101.493c27.69,-28.388 69.532,29.34 83.942,33.43c29.391,8.341 66.001,19.317 60.459,45.084c-4.119,19.147 -69.188,26.07 -82.039,29.221c-12.852,3.151 -15.381,3.779 -37.553,36.294Z" style="fill:#434343;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
<g style="filter:url(#_Effect2);">
<path d="M887.503,728.479c0,0 15.894,-29.445 14.615,-42.536c-1.279,-13.091 -67.177,-73.041 -39.424,-101.493c27.69,-28.388 69.532,29.34 83.942,33.43c29.391,8.341 66.001,19.317 60.459,45.084c-4.119,19.147 -69.188,26.07 -82.039,29.221c-12.852,3.151 -15.381,3.779 -37.553,36.294Z" style="fill:#434343;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"/>
</g>
</g>
<path d="M672.368,633.498c-0,-0 31.856,103.495 119.981,87.051c88.125,-16.444 129.545,73.261 127.572,80.472" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:9px;"/>
<path d="M941.027,678.956c-0,-0 43.242,-18.237 49.164,-24.159c0.697,-0.697 -20.115,8.077 -28.937,11.448c-4.846,1.851 -25.415,12.711 -20.227,12.711Zm-65.763,-84.565c0.981,0.981 9.94,15.582 18.407,30.183c8.468,14.601 16.444,29.202 15.463,30.184c-1.963,1.963 -43.225,-69.722 -33.87,-60.367Z" id="nostrils" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:1px;"><animate attributeName="d" begin="0s;nostrils3.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="nostrils1" to="M941.027,678.956c-0,-0 44.385,0.596 49.164,-18.604c4.779,-19.201 -25.353,-17.04 -34.175,-13.67c-4.846,1.852 -26.057,29.547 -14.989,32.274Zm-65.763,-84.565c9.954,-1.864 25.298,4.262 34.715,15.336c9.417,11.075 12.907,27.098 -0.845,45.031c-16.643,21.702 -46.874,-57.933 -33.87,-60.367Z"/><animate attributeName="d" begin="nostrils1.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="nostrils2" to="M941.027,678.956c-0,-0 44.385,0.596 49.164,-18.604c4.779,-19.201 -25.353,-17.04 -34.175,-13.67c-4.846,1.852 -26.057,29.547 -14.989,32.274Zm-65.763,-84.565c9.954,-1.864 25.298,4.262 34.715,15.336c9.417,11.075 12.907,27.098 -0.845,45.031c-16.643,21.702 -46.874,-57.933 -33.87,-60.367Z"/><animate attributeName="d" begin="nostrils2.end" dur="1000ms" fill="freeze" id="nostrils3" to="M941.027,678.956c-0,-0 43.242,-18.237 49.164,-24.159c0.697,-0.697 -20.115,8.077 -28.937,11.448c-4.846,1.851 -25.415,12.711 -20.227,12.711Zm-65.763,-84.565c0.981,0.981 9.94,15.582 18.407,30.183c8.468,14.601 16.444,29.202 15.463,30.184c-1.963,1.963 -43.225,-69.722 -33.87,-60.367Z"/></path>
<path d="M378.262,391.259c-44.772,30.19 -16.022,-68.092 32.522,-113.601c53.645,-50.29 -9.824,-42.449 -10.424,-74.046c-0.599,-31.597 300.539,-278.18 459.189,-160.546c200.64,148.769 107.416,117.626 -56.71,107.656c-109.157,-6.631 -312.99,165.291 -424.577,240.537Z" style="fill:#434132;"/>
<path d="M1018.06,639.992c-0,0 -83.794,-70.286 -34.784,-137.771c49.011,-67.485 34.15,-0.258 127.493,-27.957c49.156,-14.586 15.332,-39.879 11.529,-87.767c-3.803,-47.888 58.398,140.546 17.567,163.167c-40.83,22.621 -22.8,-44.471 -64.735,-39.486c-41.936,4.985 -82.338,20.343 -60.925,77.961c21.413,57.618 19.007,44.188 3.855,51.853Z" style="fill:#c7caab;"/>
<path d="M1235.07,510.204c-22.142,50.713 -99.804,-256.368 -168.88,-248.605c-49.132,5.522 36.505,-105.472 -4.805,-146.448c-41.31,-40.976 130.645,93.481 136.838,216.169c6.192,122.688 72.566,97.075 36.847,178.884Z" style="fill:#c7caab;"/>
<path d="M52.356,689.354c0,-0 18.398,-62.886 70.355,-66.715c52.272,-3.852 -49.634,-48.569 51.28,-108.221c44.556,-26.338 20.83,66.235 35.391,126.714c14.561,60.478 -58.286,86.654 -65.027,68.89c-6.741,-17.765 -50.149,49.164 -91.999,-20.668Z" style="fill:#799f90;"/>
<path d="M1243.04,891.109c-0,0 19.388,-10.356 30.649,12.061c11.261,22.416 18.509,29.142 -0.674,35.51c-19.183,6.368 -18.397,-3.773 -39.132,-27.278c-7.505,-8.508 -12.926,-14.875 9.157,-20.293Z" style="fill:#a3bca6;"/>
<path d="M820.715,636.96c3.651,0 10.509,1.258 12.136,5.182c2.529,6.098 2.631,13.246 3.683,19.589c7.669,46.217 -19.897,-5.243 -13.25,-18.766" style="fill:none;"/>
<path d="M826.565,644.266l-0,-0.505" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M803.97,664.549l0.496,-0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M788.903,639.898l0.994,0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M972.19,708.925l0.497,0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M992.729,727.674l0,1.491" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M967.291,734.835c-0,1.643 -0.777,5.473 0.993,5.473" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M774.437,665.011l-0,-0.505" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M754.18,627.564l0,-1.01" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M996.541,765.558c-0,-0.743 0.119,-0.386 -0.505,-1.01" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<path d="M1026.8,747.332l-0,-2.022" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:8.5px;"/>
<defs>
<image height="28px" id="_Image1" width="15px" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
<filter filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="250.665" id="_Effect2" width="250.594" x="806.471" y="527.222">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="16.3028"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

---

Here is my python & BeautifulSoup program that creates this svg

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from re import compile

def handler_from_file(filename):
    html = open(filename, 'r')
    return BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')

def group(svgs):
    """The first svg is a base img. Adds additional svgs as animation tags

    Args:
        svgs ([[string, int]]): [[svg filename, length of animation]]
    """
    base = handler_from_file(svgs[0][0])
    tags = base.find_all('path')
    soups = [handler_from_file(name) for [name, dur] in svgs]
    durs = [svg[1] for svg in svgs]

    for tag in tags:

        id = tag.get('id')
        d = tag.get('d')

        if not id:
            continue

        matches = [x for x in [s.find('path', id=id) for s in soups] if x is not None]
        if (len(matches) == 0):
            continue
        ds = [mch.get('d') for mch in matches]
        if (len(set(ds + [d])) == 1):
            continue

        # print(f"ds: {len(ds)}, durs: {len(durs)}, range: {range(1,len(ds))} ")
        for cnt in range(1,len(ds)):
            animId = f"{id}-{str(cnt)}"
            animate = base.new_tag('animate', id=animId)
            animate.attrs['to'] = ds[cnt]
            animate.attrs['attributeName'] = 'd'
            animate.attrs['dur'] = f"{durs[cnt]}ms"
            animate.attrs['fill'] = "freeze"
            
            if cnt == 1:    #If this is the first animation layer
                animate.attrs['begin'] = f"0s;{id}-{str(len(ds) - 1)}.end" #start the animation at 0s, and the end of the last animation(loops)
            else:
                animate.attrs['begin'] = f"{id}-{str(cnt - 1)}.end"     #start the animation at the end of the previous animation
            tag.append(animate)
            
    return base

def write(output, svg):
    with open(output, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(svg))


svgs = [
        ["./seal-1.svg", 1000],
        ["./seal-2.svg", 1000],
        ["./seal-3.svg", 1000],
]
output="seal-anim.svg"

animation = group(svgs)
write(output, animation)
```

---

However, with a larger example, such as [this one of someone playing trombone](https://jsfiddle.net/d09qvbes/), which has many more layers, the animation is almost working, but the original image is staying there in the background

Here are all the files on a [github repo](https://github.com/samgermain/create-animation-from-svgs) for the second svg animation, along with the script to produce it

Answer (score 1):

1. To properly animate the `<path>`s where you've added an `<animate>` tag, you need to tweak your program where `cnt == 1` to change the `fill` attribute to `"remove"` and to add a new attribute, `repeatCount` that is set to `"indefinite"`. So the outcome would look like this:

```
<animate 
     attributeName="d" 
     begin="0s;strap2-3.end" 
     dur="1500ms" 
     fill="remove"  # switch to this value
     repeatCount="indefinite"  # add this attribute
     id="strap2-1" 
     to="M1789.22,2912.33l-83.296,2.902l45.833,1758.22l83.296,-2.901l-45.833,-1758.22Z"/>
```

2. While this will fix the animations, you still have another problem which is portions of image, namely Dexter's slide hand, and the trombone fully extended, are not animated. To see what I am talking about, delete this `<path>`, for example, and the fully extended trombone will be cleaned up:

```
<path d="M4520.84,0.486c-23.469,6.567 -33.771,58.55 -33.771,58.55c-107.025,573.459 -2460.35,714.709 -2798.9,773.33c-537.992,93.166 -447.612,909.229 65.871,875.141c185.679,-12.325 979.017,-79.631 979.017,-79.631c-0,-0 -14.344,-104.849 50.82,-111.235c65.164,-6.387 71.763,100.733 71.763,100.733c220.525,-19.258 1289.13,-144.555 1289.13,-144.555c-7.646,-46.501 15.458,-77.667 48.895,-83.1c33.438,-5.438 67.598,17.3 74.109,72.012c494.963,-43.573 2721.5,-252.633 2966.35,-282.537c363.216,-44.363 601.066,328.762 109.12,377.417c-419.854,41.529 -4888.32,477.23 -5003.25,487.634l6.459,101.831c0,-0 4235.6,-392.165 5061.22,-462.528c673.929,-132.462 268.75,-706.75 -105.588,-634.912c-291.55,31.654 -5264.31,515.842 -5430.99,506.325c-573.14,-32.721 -365.372,-423.426 -90.792,-511.82c86.976,-28 669.863,-96.155 694.175,-98.83c685.163,-75.316 1788.48,-168.387 2127.44,237.771c24.904,29.846 73.358,16.659 78.658,-21.85c46.142,-335.116 -65.85,-927.987 -136.879,-1143.18c-3.667,-11.113 -13.617,-19.147 -22.854,-16.563Z" style="fill:url(#_Radial14);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
```

You'll need to decide whether to animate or delete the paths responsible for these two parts of the SVG, to get the best animation.

Comment: I don't think the repeatCount="indefinite" thing will work, I uploaded a working example for another svg if you want to take a look

Comment: example with repeatCount: https://jsfiddle.net/2aksdzmv/2/

Comment: That jsfiddle isn't what I'm looking for, there's 4 different arm positions, hence why there's 4 different svgs, and they should be put together like the result with the seal svg above

Comment: @Sam,  the example jsfiddle in the above comment *is* from running your script with the tweaks I mentioned in my answer, which groups up the svgs you supplied in the git repo.

Comment: I know it's with the tweaks in your answer, I'm saying those tweaks are not the desired effect I'm looking for